# Pyimagesearch module not found

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, image-preprocessing

I am working on an object detection tutorial using keras, tensorlow on pyimagesearch, i was not able to subscribe on the pyimagesearch site therefore i couldn't get the pyimagesearch folder. Please is there a way i could run the code without using the folder?.

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-8215065cc4e1> in <module>()
----> 1 from pyimagesearch import config
      2 from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16
      3 from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten, Dense, Input
      4 from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
      5 from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyimagesearch'
```

Answer (score 0):

because, its implemented by user defined class and import from that pyimagesearch Gsearch for adrianrosebrock